# Typescript get array of all children and grandchildren id's from parent id

Tags: typescript, recursion, parent-child, hierarchical

Suppose I have an array of objects showing hierarchical data:

```
const data = [
  { groupId: 1, parentGroupId: null },
  { groupId: 2, parentGroupId: 1 },
  { groupId: 3, parentGroupId: 1 },
  { groupId: 4, parentGroupId: null },
  { groupId: 5, parentGroupId: 99 },
  { groupId: 6, parentGroupId: 2 },
  { groupId: 7, parentGroupId: 6 },
  { groupId: 8, parentGroupId: 4 }];
```

How might one write a recursive typescript function that would take a parentGroupId parameter and return an array of groupId's including its own groupId and the groupId's of all its children, grandchildren, great-grandchildren, and so on recursively.

ie. the function should return:

```
[1,2,3,6,7]
```

So far I have a function that returns the parent and its children, but I'm missing the recursive part to also include grandchildren, great-grandchildren, and so on.

```
 const data = [
          { groupId: 1, parentGroupId: null },
          { groupId: 2, parentGroupId: 1 },
          { groupId: 3, parentGroupId: 1 },
          { groupId: 4, parentGroupId: null },
          { groupId: 5, parentGroupId: 99 },
          { groupId: 6, parentGroupId: 2 },
          { groupId: 7, parentGroupId: 6 },
          { groupId: 8, parentGroupId: 4 }];
          
    function getChildIds(arr, parentGroupId) {
      return arr.reduce(function (ret, item) {
        if (item.parentGroupId == parentGroupId || item.groupId == parentGroupId) {
          ret = ret.concat(item.groupId);
        }
        return ret;
      }, []);
    }

    console.log(getChildIds(data, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with this function:

```
function getChildIds(arr: any[], parentGroupId: number) {
  return arr.reduce(function (ret: any[], item: any) {
    if (item.parentGroupId == parentGroupId) {
      ret = ret.concat(item.groupId, getChildIds(arr, item.groupId));
    }
    return ret;
  }, []);
}
```

Which gets every ID except the original parent ID, which I then push to the array afterwards

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).